# Error trying to connect sql server with RoR app in Vagrant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, debian, vagrant, tiny-tds

I'm trying to connect RoR app with SQL Server. I have created a `database.yml` file, like the following:

```
development: 
   <<: *default 
   adapter: sqlserver
   host: 'pcname\domain' 
   encoding: 'unicode' 
   database: 'db_name' 
   username: 'user' 
   password: 'pass' 
   pool: 5 
   port: 1434
```

I've enabled TPC/IP and changed the port to 1434 in SQL Configuration Manager.

When I tried to run a migration with `rake db:migrate` the console throws:

> TinyTds::Error: Server name not found in configuration files

I've installed FreeTDS previously. And I've tried with `dataserver: 'pcname\domain:1434'` and `dataserver: 'pcname\domain'` without port

Full trace

```
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/tiny_tds-2.0.0/lib/tiny_tds/client.rb:54:in connect'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/tiny_tds-2.0.0/lib/tiny_tds/client.rb:54:ininitialize' /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:375:in new'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:375:indblib_connect' /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:361:in connect'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:59:ininitialize' /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-5.2.0/lib/active_record/sqlserver_base.rb:13:in new'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-5.2.0/lib/active_record/sqlserver_base.rb:13:insqlserver_connection' /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:811:in new_connection'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:855:incheckout_new_connection' /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:834:in try_to_checkout_new_connection'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:795:inacquire_connection' /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:523:in checkout'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:382:inconnection' /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1014:in retrieve_connection'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:118:inretrieve_connection' /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:90:in connection'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:172:inmigrate'/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:60:in block (2 levels) in <main>'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in' /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in eval'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in' Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Vagrant file

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://vagrantcloud.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "jaxmetalmax/debian8-rubydev"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # NOTE: This will enable public access to the opened port
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine and only allow access
  # via 127.0.0.1 to disable public access
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"
  config.vm.synced_folder "C:/EGodoy/Sites", "/home/vagrant/sites"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  #   vb.memory = "1024"
  # end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  # config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  #   apt-get update
  #   apt-get install -y apache2
  # SHELL
end
```

Comment: how does your vagrant file looks like?

Comment: I've edited the post and added vagrant file

Comment: just to be clear, SQL server is installed on the vagrant VM or the host machine?

Comment: Host machine. I work in vagrant, but i tried installing ruby, rails,  freetds, and all pre-requirements in the host machine (Windows 10), and I get same error

Comment: If i use only 'pcname' in host, i get this error 'TinyTds::Error: closed connection'

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you are not forwarding any ports between your vagrant VM and your host machine, which you need to do for RoR that is running on the VM to be able to connect to the port of SQL server that is running on the host machine. Add this line in the vagrant file:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 1434, host: 1434
```

and you will probably also need to uncomment this line so that you can access your RoR site:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
```

or change the port above to whatever port you are running RoR on (i believe 3000 is the default, so `3000` instead of `80`)

Comment: I changed the above and i get the same error.
I´ve tried with vm_tiny_tds-2.1.2 gem instead of tiny_tds-2.0.0 too

Comment: to be sure, you have installed those gems on the VM machine right? i'm thinking in your `database.yml` file the `host` should be `localhost` instead of what you have. Also be sure to restart vagrant after you have added those port fowarding configs to the vagrant file.

Comment: yes, I restarted vagrant when i changed ports. Gems are installed in VM, freeTDS too. And I tried with localhost and it didn't work either.